# arduino wifi shield not present error

Tags: wifi

I'm using an HLK-RM04 WIFI shield and arduino uno R3 board. whenever I mount my shield on the uno board and connect it to the pc using a usb only the power led(red) of my wifi shield glows. I tried to upload the example code on wifi(provided by arduino)but whenever I run the code it shows "wifi shield not present". Looking into the previous discussions on this website I even tried to connect my arduino with usb+9v supply. In that case my trackpad of the laptop ceases to work. whenever I power my system(arduino+shield) using a 9v external supply all the 3 leds(power,link,wan led) on my wifi shield glow but still the same error of "wifi shield not present" persists.

What is going wrong?

Has anyone configured an HLK-rm04 wifi shield with uno r3 before?

Thanks

Comment: unfortunately i gave up using hlk-rm04 wifi module for my application.
it was too power hungry and there was very little online help available.

Answer (score 0):

I DON'T have experience with the shield you are mentioning, but it sounds to me that no data is being sent from the WiFi shield to the Arduino.  I suggest you do a bit of debugging with:

1) Print Statements
2) A multimeter (better yet, an oscilloscope)
3) Check that the pins you are connecting the shield to are not blown

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE! Can you expand your post a bit to explain how to use these to debug the problem of the OP? To me, it doesn't seem like these would fix a computer error, but feel free to elaborate on how this would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of a non-compatible version of the Arduino IDE? (latest version isn't always the fittest, apparently).

I found evidence for this weird behavior in various forums around the web - even when using the Uno R3 board with its official WiFi shield, I had to go back to version 1.0.3 of the Arduino IDE (and to flush its compatible firmware version for the WiFi shield) in order to get the sample code to work. Later versions just didn't work!

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE! Do you have any evidence that this works for wifi shields? If so, can you please edit your post? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I do have, but I couldn't comment in the original post :(

Comment: Ok, if you have evidence, can you please edit your post? Thanks.

Comment: Is it ok now? :)